# mounting /tmp to a container based lambda from inside of calling lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have an automation task that uses a lambda which calls two other lambdas. The first invoked lambda, lambda 1, fetches some data, processes it and writes it to `/tmp`. The other lambda, lambda 2, was intended to be run by reading the file written to `/tmp` before uploading to another location outside of AWS. The upload lambda 2 is based off a docker image. Is it possible to mount `/tmp` from the runtime of the lambda calling lambda 2 so lambda 2 can read the file written by lambda 1?

If this is not possible the only other alternative would be to use either a EFS file system or pass the data directly into lambda 2's payload as a string correct? These files are not too large so I am thinking of passing the string into the payload directly as the alternative option.

Comment: Not possible using standard Lambda runtime environment. Use EFS or S3 or send the content via SQS (triggering the 2nd Lambda) are some options, or directly invoke Lambda 2 with the encoded payload (not the best option imo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Lambda functions don't share the same disk. The best way to share state in this use case would be with something like S3.